# AbstractList guarantees that spill into other methods

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I can't think of a better name for the question, but I hope that an example will make this simpler.

Suppose I create my own custom `List` (it is irrelevant what it does):

```
    static class MyList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {

        @Override
        public E get(int index) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I can now create an instance of it and call a different method then the one I have overridden:

```
MyList<String> myList = new MyList<>();
myList.iterator();
```

Of course, `iterator` *should* use the `get` method that I have declared, but is this a guarantee? Does it mean that `iterator` can not change in a way that it does not use `get` at all?

---

For a simpler example, you can think about `addAll`. Suppose that my `MyList` also overrides `add`:

```
   @Override
   public boolean add(E e) {
      return super.add(e); // irrelevant what it does
   }
```

and then I can do : `myList.addAll(someOtherCollection)`. `addAll` *could* be implemented a simple:

```
for(E e: someOtherCollection) {
    // use add that I have overridden
}
```

but at the same time, the implementation can change, and not use a loop at all (like `ArrayList` for example).

---

Granted, both `iterator` and `addAll` have some mentions in the documentation like:

> This implementation returns a straightforward implementation of the iterator interface, relying on the backing list's size(), get(int), and remove(int) methods.

and

> This implementation iterates over the specified collection, and adds each object returned by the iterator to this collection, in turn.

So does that mean that this can *NOT* change and is treated as "specification"?  Now that I wrote this long question and re-read it, the answer might be an obvious "yes".

Comment: Couldn't you just override AbstractList's `iterator()` method and return your own iterator implementation?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I could, but of course we are not talking about a single method here. The custom List that I am writing will be exposed to other people, I don't know what they will call

Comment: Then, have you looked at the source code for AbstractList?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's not the point, source code != specification.

Comment: I’d pay attention to the class documentation saying “*If the list is variable-size the programmer must additionally override the add(int, E) and remove(int) methods.*”, hence, care to override `add(int, E)` rather than `add(E)` but besides that, how would a hypothetical `addAll` implementation look like when it doesn’t invoke `add`?

Comment: @Holger thank you, I ended up indeed reading much more closely the class documentation and overriding proper methods. The `addAll` without `add` is what ArrayList does... or is your point different?

Comment: @Eugene the question was, how would *AbstractList* implement an `addAll` without calling `add`, directly or indirectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html) for AbstractList (JDK21) says

> The documentation for each non-abstract method in this class describes its implementation in detail.

So yes, this is part of the specification.

Comment: The class documentation also says it explicitly: “*Unlike the other abstract collection implementations, the programmer does not have to provide an iterator implementation; the iterator and list iterator are implemented by this class, on top of the "random access" methods: get(int), set(int, E), add(int, E) and remove(int).*” as part of the class’s contract, additionally to the the “Implementation Requirements” section of the methods.

Answer (score -2):

No, there’s no such guarantee. This is because `iterator()` is a method of `Iterable<T>`.

It may, and maybe should, but there’s no guarantee.

You can look at the implementation of `ArrayList<T>.addAll()` to get a sense of why.

Comment: if that is true, then what is the point of `AbstractList`? Why is it exposed into the public API to begin with? Besides `iterator` in my case, would be the one from `AbstractList`, I fail to get your point with `Iterable`.

Comment: Also, `ArrayList` overrides _all_ methods, so it has the right to do what it does in `addAll`, unlike my implementation, where I override only 2/3 methods.

Comment: When you derive from an abstract class you must implement all the abstract methods (the exception is of your class is also abstract). You may override other methods if you wish to, but you don’t have to.

Comment: List is an interface therefore ArrayList, and other implementations, must override all methods.

Comment: "This is because iterator() is a method of Iterable<T>." What has that to do with anything? Classes implementing an Interface CAN add additional guarantees.

Comment: @Sören how can it be guaranteed when it’s a function coming from a different interface? They CAN, that does not mean it’s guaranteed. 
IMO adding guarantees without enforcing them using abstract classes or a different mechanism means the guarantee is weak and should not be trusted.

Comment: That guarantee can be made by never changing the implementation. It's that simple.

Comment: What do you mean with “*adding guarantees without enforcing them using abstract classes*”? The question is specifically about a guaranty provided by an abstract class.